# How to return precisely output values of bash script has command

Tags: python, bash, shell, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I have the following command:

```
$ snmpnetstat -v2c -c public -Cs -Cp udp 10.10.0.32
```

**that has the terminal output:**

```
udp:
           198 total datagrams received
            65 datagrams to invalid port
             0 datagrams dropped due to errors
           265 output datagram requests
```

I want to write a bash script that returns the following:

**the desired output of bash script:**

```
Received Datagrams: 198 
Invalid port:65 
Dropped datagrams: 0 
Datagram requests: 256
```

I started with:

```
#!/bin/bash
    rs="$(snmpnetstat -v2c -c public -Cs -Cp udp 10.10.0.32)"
ReceivedDatagrams=$(echo $rs | cut -d"/" -f1)
InvalidPort=$(echo $rs | cut -d"/" -f2)
DroppedDatagrams=$(echo $rs | cut -d"/" -f3)
DatagramRequests=$(echo $rs | cut -d"/" -f4)

echo "Received Datagrams:$ReceivedDatagrams Invalid port:$InvalidPort Dropped datagrams:$DroppedDatagrams Datagram requests:$DatagramRequests"
```

The output is:

```
    zsz@bme-ib112-05:~/bash_scripts$ ./script.sh         
Received Datagrams:udp: 242 total datagrams received 37 datagrams to invalid port 0 datagrams dropped due to errors 638 output datagram requests Invalid port:udp: 242 total datagrams received 37 datagrams to invalid port 0 datagrams dropped due to errors 638 output datagram requests Dropped datagrams:udp: 242 total datagrams received 37 datagrams to invalid port 0 datagrams dropped due to errors 638 output datagram requests Datagram requests:udp: 242 total datagrams received 37 datagrams to invalid port 0 datagrams dropped due to errors 638 output datagram requests
```

The output values are repeating over and over and not as I wanted.

Comment: Quote your variables. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes. Also use `printf` with `\n`s where appropriate rather than `echo`.

Comment: Why are you using "/" as your cut delimiter? I think the following approach might be a good starting point; wrap your rs variable in quotes so it doesn't expand, and then adjust your cut delimiters. Something like 

rs="$(snmpnetstat -v2c -c public -Cs -Cp udp 10.10.0.32)"   

ReceivedDatagrams="$(echo $rs | cut -d$'\n' -f2 | tr -s ' '| cut -d' ' -f2)"

Also, `echo` might give you trouble with newlines, you might want to check out the usage of print() instead

Comment: This is a very "expensive" solution to your problem. All of the `$(cmd-substitutions)`, `|` (pipes) etc indicate extra process creations. You could create your report with one extra process. Spend some time working thru the [Awk Tutorial](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) . Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't recreate the exact output of the `snmpnetstat` command, so I just copy/pasted your terminal output into a file `tmp`.

The following script does the job you requested on my end, using your logic

I'd recommend taking shellter's and Ed Morton's advice and look through how quoting variables works to disallow expansion in whitespace/newlines, and using Awk for a more robust and easily extendable solution.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

rs="$(cat tmp)"

# You have to quote "$rs" so newlines don't break
ReceivedDatagrams="$(echo "$rs" | cut -d$'\n' -f2 | tr -s ' '| cut -d' ' -f2)"
InvalidPort="$(echo "$rs" | cut -d$'\n' -f3 | tr -s ' '| cut -d' ' -f2)"
DroppedDatagrams="$(echo "$rs" | cut -d$'\n' -f4 | tr -s ' '| cut -d' ' -f2)"
DatagramRequests="$(echo "$rs" | cut -d$'\n' -f5 | tr -s ' '| cut -d' ' -f2)"

echo "Received Datagrams:$ReceivedDatagrams"
echo "Invalid port:$InvalidPort"
echo "Dropped datagrams:$DroppedDatagrams"
echo "Datagram requests:$DatagramRequests"
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple `awk` solution that, as shellter's pointed out, eliminates the overhead of all those extra processes:

```
$ cat udp.out
udp:
           198 total datagrams received
            65 datagrams to invalid port
             0 datagrams dropped due to errors
           265 output datagram requests

$ awk '
/received/ {printf "Received Datagrams: %s\n", $1}
/invalid/  {printf "Invalid port: %s\n"      , $1}
/dropped/  {printf "Dropped datagrams: %s\n" , $1}
/requests/ {printf "Datagram requests: %s\n" , $1}
' udp.out

Received Datagrams: 198
Invalid port: 65
Dropped datagrams: 0
Datagram requests: 265
```

Comment: Well, I guess we are on the same page (and name).

Answer (score 3):

If you don't really want the values assigned to variables, and strictly looking to reformat the output, you might have cleaner code with awk as follows:

```
awk '
/total datagrams/                 { print "Received Datagrams:", $1 }
/datagrams to invalid port/       { print "Invalid port:", $1 }
/datagrams dropped due to errors/ { print "Dropped datagrams:", $1 }
/output datagram requests/        { print "Datagram requests:", $1 } 
'
```

In a sense, awk is doing all the parsing for you and squeezing (`tr -s`) out all of your whitespace.  I believe it makes the code easier to read.